# How to change menu item text from custom adapter

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android. In my **fragment** i have  a listview. Each list item contains a button in an adapter. If i click the button from the adapter i want to Change the menu text. I wrote some code but it shows error. I don't know how to use that code in fragment. Please anyone guide me!

MyFragment:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.total, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

public static void setMenuItem(String title){

    Menu menu = (Menu) getActivity.getMenu();  // Error:Cannot resolve symbol getActivity

    MenuItem quantit = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_total);
    quantit.setTitle(title);  // Error:Cannot resolve symbol quantit

}
```

Adapter:

```
MyFragment.setMenuItem(title);
```

Thanks in advance!